# Style Trigger stops to work after direct SetValue

Tags: wpf, triggers, wpf-style

Setting BackgroundProperty directly breaks IsMouseOver Style Trigger. How to have possiblity to set BackgroundProperty directly and retain trigger to work after that?

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTriggers.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OriginalBackground" Color="Blue"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TemplateBackground" Color="Red"/>
        <Style TargetType="Label" >
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource OriginalBackground}"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            </Style.Setters>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource TemplateBackground}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Focusable="True" x:Name="label">Hi!</Label>
            <Button Click="Button_Click">Over</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
   </Window>
```

Code behind:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
namespace WpfTriggers
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow() => InitializeComponent();    
        void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => label.SetValue(Control.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Green);       
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We solved issue by copying style, temporally replacing it by clone with background setter and returning style back. This was made into production as  behavior which imitates data trigger with fully custom dynamic binding.

```
    public static class extensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Shallow clone of style.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="original">Style to clone.</param>
    /// <returns>Cloned style.</returns>
    public static Style ShallowClone(this Style original)
    {
        var cloned = new Style(original.TargetType, original.BasedOn);
        foreach (var s in original.Setters) cloned.Setters.Add(s);
        foreach (var t in original.Triggers) cloned.Triggers.Add(t);
        cloned.Resources = original.Resources;
        return cloned;
    }
}

    Style old;

    private void Button_MouseEnter_5(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        old = labelWithMofidiableStyle.Style;
        Style style = old.ShallowClone();
        style.Setters.Add(new Setter { Property = Control.BackgroundProperty, Value = this.FindResource("DynamicBackground") });
        labelWithMofidiableStyle.Style = style;
    }



    private void Button_MouseLeave_5(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        labelWithMofidiableStyle.Style = old;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't set properties that used in styles directly (the result is your sample).
You must use Binding instead.
Some addings to your code:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
        SetValue(BgBrushProperty, Resources["OriginalBackground"]);
    }

    void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => SetValue(BgBrushProperty, Brushes.Green);


    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for BgBrush.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BgBrushProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BgBrush", typeof(Brush), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata());
```

and in XAML...

```
 <Style.Setters>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding BgBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
</Style.Setters>
```

And also you can use DynamicResource like that:

```
<Style.Setters>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource OriginalBackground}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
</Style.Setters>
```

with this code:

```
    public MainWindow() => InitializeComponent();
    void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => Resources["OriginalBackground"] = Brushes.Green;
```

Comment: Binding and DataContext work overall, but the Label has inherited DataContext and binds onto it.  DataContext  object should not be enriched with Background. I could try to create dynamic binding which rebinds-wraps relevant data from DataContext into custom object with Background, but looks complex.

Comment: DynamicResource works. I create StaticResource with same name on Window level to have initial default value. And then override on Label level. Will check for issues before making this as answer.

Comment: @DzmitryLahoda in solution with DataContext you can also use RelativeSource, to not to enrich inherited DataContext